# `text` method removes space between words in some case

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

From my container, I am trying to `fetch` the `text`. But some reasons, i am not getting the `word space` between some scenario. i am not get the exact issue here and how to fix that too..

In this `html` i have very limited control, since i am getting the `html` from server.

Any one give me a solution please?

```js
var myText = $('.textHighLight').text();
$('#parent').before(myText);

//look in to here: ANDMAINTENANCE, OFAL-GHARAFA (both AND and OF) lost their space.
```

```css
#parent{
    border:1px solid red;
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <div style="white-space:pre;"><span class="cls_3 textHighLight userNote1">CONSTRUCTION</span><span class="cls_4 textHighLight userNote1"> </span><span class="cls_3 textHighLight userNote1">COMPLETION</span><span class="cls_4 textHighLight userNote1"> </span><span class="cls_3 textHighLight userNote1">AND</span></div>
<div style="white-space:pre;"><span class="cls_3 textHighLight userNote1">MAINTENANCE</span><span class="cls_4 textHighLight userNote1"> </span><span class="cls_3 textHighLight userNote1">OF</span><span class="cls_4 textHighLight userNote1"> </span><span class="cls_3 textHighLight userNote1">OUTDOOR</span><span class="cls_4 textHighLight userNote1"> </span><span class="cls_3 textHighLight userNote1">COOLING</span><span class="cls_4 textHighLight userNote1"> </span><span class="cls_3 textHighLight userNote1">OF</span></div>
<div style="white-space:pre;"><span class="cls_3 textHighLight userNote1">AL-GHARAFA</span><span class="cls_4 textHighLight userNote1"> </span><span class="cls_3 textHighLight userNote1">SPORTS</span><span class="cls_4 textHighLight userNote1"> </span><span class="cls_3 textHighLight userNote1">CLUB</span><span class="cls_4 textHighLight userNote1"> </span><span class="cls_3 textHighLight userNote1">FOR</span><span class="cls_4 textHighLight userNote1"> </span><span class="cls_3 textHighLight userNote1">ASPIRE</span></div>
<div style="white-space:pre;"><span class="cls_3 textHighLight userNote1">ZONE</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are no spaces elemenated in your code, you see empty spans,

```
  <span class="cls_4 textHighLight userNote1"> </span>
```

this is where the spaces are added in some cases, either remove them and go with [DemoUser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28980590/3556874)

Or just add them, where they are not added. See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/fpars9px/)

Answer (score 1):

you line `var myText = $('.textHighLight').text();` gets text from element with class `textHighLight` as single string, you need to use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to loop thru all the elements and pass in the text and append it, as:

```
var textArr = [];
$.each( $('.textHighLight'), function(idx, v) {
    textArr.push($(v).html());
});
$('#parent').before(textArr.join(" "));
```

Comment: there are no spaces actually elemenated in OPs code, they are just not there in some cases